# Message Queue Error

Tags: c#, windows, msmq, nservicebus

I am using the Microsoft Message Queueing service in combination with the NTServiceBus (Eventbroker).

The application is running on a client´s pc with the Message Queueing Service installed. The eventbroker works as it is supposed to and everything works finde. But every now an then... 2-3 times a month maybe, the software crashes with the following exception:

```
NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus|Failed to subscribe to
Appccelerate.DistributedEventBroker.NServiceBus.Messages.INServiceBusEventFired,
Appccelerate.DistributedEventBroker.NServiceBus, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=917bca444d1f2b4c at publisher queue frontkomm.net@kkl
NServiceBus.Unicast.Queuing.QueueNotFoundException: Failed to send message to address:
[frontkomm.net@kkl] ---> System.Messaging.MessageQueueException: The queue does   
not exist or you do not have sufficient permissions to perform the operation.
```

If it wouldn´t work at all, this error would make sense to me... but why is it just crashing once in a while?

Comment: Do you need just a restart to recover?

Answer (score 1):

This error can occur when you exceed the MSMQ storage quota limits (default value is 1 GB for sum of bytes all queues). Check if your consumer can handle the amount of messages you send. The MSMQ performance counters are good tools to monitor this (MSMQ Service > Total bytes in all queues, for instance).

If you have bursts of messages that make you hit the quota, you could possibly need to increase the quota. This is done in the Computer Management console > Services and Applications > Message Queuing > Properties.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will look into it in the next weeks, and keep you informed.